# Custom type for express.js Request interface

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am trying to change type of query in Express.js Request namespace. I allready using a custom atrribute, but this approach seems not working if attribute is already declared in @types (works just for new attributes added to Request).

This is my type declaration:

```
declare namespace Express {
    export interface Query { [key: string]: any; }

    export interface Request {
        attr1?: string, // this is working
        query: any      // this is not working, query is still type of Query
    }
}
```

and this is my ts.config

```
  "typeRoots" : [
            "./src/types",
            "node_modules/@types"
        ]
```

Is there some another approach, how to redefine type of query attribute? (or another attribute from Request interface)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems only solution is use an [`Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktk)

```
import { Request as OriginalRequest } from 'express'

declare namespace Express {
    export interface Request extends Omit<OriginalRequest, 'query'> {
        query: any
    }
}
```